# Tricky calculation using formulas in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I try to calculate the sum of all possible shifts a person can take during a period based on availability:

[image]

Assume empty is equivalent to available in scheme number 2.

This is what I got so far:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$14:$B$15=$C$2)*$C$14:$E$15)
```

Hence, I obtain:

[image]

This should be the final result:

[image]

I still have to somehow check if an employee is available a given day before adding the number to the sum.

And Tuesday, where there is need two employees for shift blue, it should only count one of them.

**Update**

Thanks for asking. Here is an explanation of the result:

CT can't work Monday, can work Tuesday (empty is equivalent to available), hence 1 blue Tuesday (not possible to cover both blue), and on Wednesday CT can cover 1 red. Summing red gives 1 and summing blue gives 1 for CT's entry.

Da can work 1 red Monday, and 1 red Wednesday and is not available for working blue on Tuesday. Summing red gives 2 and blue gives 0.

JAN can work 1 red Monday and 1 blue Tuesday.

Comment: Can you explain the result? Why is CT 1 for Red an Blue, when CT is only availabe for wed and wed is blue = 2 and red= 0?

Comment: @MG92 They are available if it says "available" in the table or nothing.

Comment: Missread the entries of the second scheme

Comment: Sorry for bad explanation, it is indeed not self-explanatory. I tried to add some more details to the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the following setup:

[image]

In B2 (drag down as needed) I used:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--($B7:$D7<>$B$7),--($B$12:$D$12>0))`

And in C2 i used:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--($B7:$D7<>$B$7);--($B$13:$D$13>0))`

Comment: Thank you so much. I couldn't really get my head around this, and got stuck in overcomplicating everything. Can you explain what is going on. In particular the ```--```-part

Comment: This `($B7:$D7<>$B$7)` returns a Array of booleans (TRUE or FALSE). In order to get the corresponding numerical value (TRUE = 1 and FALSE = 1), we use this `--`. What it does it puts a negativ value infront of the boolean value and converts it into an numeric value (-TRUE-> -1 and -FALSE -> 0) and then we negate it aggain (--1 -> +1 and --0 -> 0). I hope that was clear.

Comment: The first part checks, if the person is available on a weekday (`($B7:$D7<>$B$7)`) and the second part checks if red/blue needs to be covered on a given weekday (`($B$13:$D$13>0)`) since one person cannot cover multiple shifts, i just check if red/blue is need (the `>0`part).

Comment: Perfectly clear. And a very useful way of solving problems.